# How to rotate a circle around the y-axis and calculate the volume of the 3D solid?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, scripting

How do I rotate the equation ${(x-5)^2}+{y^2}={3^2}$ around the y-axis and calculate the volume of the plotted 3D solid?
I tried the code below but the result doesn't work.

```
Show[{RevolutionPlot3D[(x - 5)^2 + (y^2) == (3^2), {x, -100, 
    100}, {y, -100, 100}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, 
   PlotRange -> {-1, 20}], 
  Graphics3D[{Text["x", Scaled[{-.05, .5, 0}], {0, -1}], 
    Text["y", Scaled[{.5, -.05, 0}], {0, -1}], 
    Text["z", Scaled[{.5, .5, 1.1}]]}]}, Boxed -> False, 
 RevolutionAxis -> "Y"]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We define a region by

```
f[x_, y_] := (x - 5)^2 + y^2 - 3^2;
reg2=ImplicitRegion[f[x, y] <= 0, {x, y}]
reg2// Region
```

[image]

Then the implicit equation of  revolution  is `f[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], z] <= 0`.

```
f[x_, y_] := (x - 5)^2 + y^2 - 3^2;
reg3=ImplicitRegion[f[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], z] <= 0, {x, y, z}]
reg3//Volume
RegionPlot3D[DiscretizeRegion[reg3, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01]]
```

> `90 π^2`

[image]

For another implicit region, for example, an elliptical disk the method also works.

```
g[x_, y_] := (x - 5)^2 + 2 y^2 - 3^2;
reg3 = ImplicitRegion[g[Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], z] <= 0, {x, y, z}];
reg3 // Volume
(* 45 Sqrt[2] π^2 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

RevolutionPlot3D needs a parametric representation of the curve.
For your circle, try this code, modified from the 2nd example in the documentation for RevolutionPlot3D:

```
 RevolutionPlot3D[{5 + 3 Cos[t], 3 Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Answer (score 3):

The volume may be calculated either by a formula:

```
V== 2 Pi^2 r^2 R 
2 Pi^2 3^2 5 == 90 Pi^2 == 888.264
```

or using integration of 2 Pi x, the circumference of the circle a x/y point describes during rotation, over the x/y circle:

```
NIntegrate[2 Pi x, {x, 2, 8}, {y, -Sqrt[9 - (x - 5)^2], Sqrt[9 - (x - 5)^2]}]
```

alternatively, we may use the "ImplicitRegion" command for the integral :

```
ir = ImplicitRegion[(x - 5)^2 + y^2 <= 9, {x, y}]
NIntegrate[2 Pi x, {x, y} \[Element] ir]
```